# How to Get Rid if Intermediary Page in Searchable Dictionary-Like App

Tags: android, search, dictionary, sample, searchable

I am working on a search app and since I am a beginner, I decided to start from the searchable dictionary sample, which is quite similar to what I'm trying to achieve. Got it to work, but I have a problem: the sample loads a blank page initially, telling the user to press on the search button to start performing a search. Once search is pressed, a new page loads with a search field and button on top, allowing the user to start searching for stuff.

What I want to do is get rid of that intermediary page, so that the search field and button are loaded from the beginning, on the very first screen the app loads when started. Any ideas on how to do this? Detailed instructions/examples would be greatly appreciated, as I am a beginner in Android programming.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just call onSearchRequested() from your Activity that should open the search screen This method exists in every class that extends Activity. Search controls are then just overlayed on top of the current screen.